# PHP data is to Ajax as RoR data is to X?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, jquery, database-design

I'm learning about RoR, and prior to this, I was working on PHP and Ajax.

If I have a scenario with two divs, and user can click on either one (I have done some jquery styling so when user clicks on either divs, it will show styling that they clicked on the div, Note: these are not buttons), then I would need to place some data into database:

```
<div class="neat" id="customer">
 Customer
</div>

<div class="neat" id="developer>
 Developer
</div>
```

When I used to develop with PHP, I can set some kind of ajax/jquery so when user clicks on either div, I can send the respective div id to ajax and save some kind of data (customer or developer) from the id attribute into my database.

```
$('.neat').on('click',function(){
  $this = $(this);
  $.ajax({
   type: POST,
   url: save.php,
   data : cust_or_deve = $this.attr("id")
  });
});
```

**// save.php**

```
if($_POST['cust_or_deve']){
 $type = $_POST['cust_or_deve'];
 // store database syntax
}
```

Now, learning RoR, I'm trying to figure out how would they save the data? Would I do the same method or is there some kind of easier way to store data from what I used to do?

Comment: "Server-side is to client-side, as a different server-side is to X"?

Answer (score 0):

X = Ajax

RoR is a backend framework for the language ruby. So ruby is kind of like php, rails is the framework. Just like PHP is the language, and CodeIgniter or dJango are frameworks.

AJAX is a client-side http request (framework, i guess). AJAX can send information to the server, or get information from the server, which could be either RoR or PHP.

**rails is not the only ruby framework**

while it is wildly more popular, there are others, like Sinatra. Rails is primarily used as an engine for receiving, processing, storing, and representing data.

So to answer your question, PHP is to AJAX as RoR is to AJAX. A more apt analogy would be RoR is to PHP as Java is to C++, similar purpose, just a different flavor.